Bootable pen drive becomes disfunctional when I flash the iso file into it
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11 back in 2022.
Now I tried to reuse the same pen drive to install Ubuntu 24.04.1. When I tried to flash the ISO into the pen it told me it could not format because the drive was write-protected. However, when I check diskpart in Windows CMD read-only mode is NOT active. Moreover, the pen appeared as unusable and partitioned in two volumes. I tried running among other things to run clean on the pen. It also did not work.
I bought a brand new pen drive the same problem is happening. Note that I am using balenaEtcher for the flashing process.
I came here because I do not know what else to try. I would like to know if someone has a similar experience or at least some kind of suggestion.
Thank you in advance.

This question is similar to: How to restore original size and unboot my bootable USB pendrive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
